# Get the value of a particular element with JavaScript that is looped with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ";
                  $res = query($sql);
                  foreach($res as $row) {
                  
                  ?>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['user'] ?></td>
                      <td><img src= '<?php echo $row['pix'] ?>' alt='image' ></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['phone'] ?></td>
                      <td>
                      <span class="icon-sm">
                      <input id="username" hidden value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"> 
                        <a onclick="check()"><i class="mdi mdi-check-bold" style="color: green; cursor: pointer;"></i></a>
                        <a><i onclick="del()" class="mdi mdi-delete" style="color: #001737; cursor: pointer ;"><p id="del" hidden><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p></i></a>
                        <a onclick="email()"><i class="mdi mdi-email" style="color: #001737; cursor: pointer;"></i></a>
```

Above is a loop from my db. Onclick of some icons, I want javascript to perform some actions. To  perform these actions, I have to pick `<?php echo $row['name'] ?>` and I have got that from `<input id="username" hidden value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">`. The issue I am having now is that JavaScript will only pick the first id. This is because `<input id="username" hidden value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">` is being looped and Javascript will pick the first.

I have tried many methods but didn't work. Please what can I do?

Comment: Your code lacks of constitancy. Near the begining, you have `if ($ver === 0)` (`$ver` being checked against a **numeric** value). Then, later in the HTML code, you have `if ($ver === '1')` this time, checked against a **string**. The triple equality operator `===` will check the value **and** the type and won't perform implicit conversions

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document. Since you are still using inline event handlers here, you could simply pass the values you need as parameters in the function call, then you don't need the hidden input field any more. Or you could rewrite this to use a halfway contemporary methods, i.e. proper event handler binding via script. And then navigate to the corresponding target element by making use of the relation of the elements in the DOM - go up to a common parent element first, and then select the input in there, based on a _class_ instead of id.

Comment: Or do away with the input field, and put the data you need into custom data attributes directly on the element where the event occurs.

Comment: Cid, although I don't have ay errors from that parts as they it works well. I have edited the codes to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in hidden field append user_id with 'username' like this

```
<input id="username<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" hidden value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
```

and in onclick method pass user_id like this

```
<a onclick="check(<?php echo  $row['user_id']; ?>)">
```

and then in javascript you can select that value

```
function check(id){
    var data=$('#username'+id).val();
}
```